# Qt: How to open a new main window on push button click and delete original main window?

Tags: c++, qt

I have files `main.cpp`, `MainWindow.h` and `MainWindow.cpp`. I have a push button on this original main window. What I want is when I click on the button, it should take me to a new main window and delete the original main window.

Also I want to follow good programming practices. So I am wondering that should new source and header files like `SecondWindow.cpp/.h` be created or all this be done in `MainWindow.cpp` where I have definition of the `SLOT` `on_button_clicked()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Instantiate the new window and show it.
2. Delete the current window once the control returns to the event loop.

   ```
   void MainWindow::on_button_clicked() {
     auto win = new MainWindow();
     win->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
     win->show();
     deleteLater();
   }
   ```
3. Make sure that the initial instance of the window is created on the heap:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     auto win = new MainWindow;
     win->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose );
     win->show(); 
     return app.exec();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Kuba Ober works.However, you can have only 2 main windows at all times no matter how many times you press the button. It seems to crash the program after the second time you run it.
I believe my solution would be better since you can open as many main windows.

At your MainWindow Header:

```
private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
MainWindow *nWin; //Add This bit of code here
```

As for your triggered event function:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{
   nWin = new MainWindow;
   nWin->show();

}
```

That should do it.

Thanks.